# Primality criterion

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, primality-test

Can you provide a proof or a counterexample for the claim given below ?

Inspired by Theorem 4 in [this paper](http://icm.mcs.kent.edu/reports/1999/chebpol.pdf) I have formulated the following claim :

> Let $P_n^{(a)}(x)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot\left(\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+a}\right)^n+\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+a}\right)^n\right)$ . Given an odd integer $ n$ ($ \geq 3 $) and integer $ a$ coprime to $ n$ , $ n$ is prime if and only if $ P_n^{(a)}(x) \equiv x^n \pmod{n} $ holds .

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNjEEKwjAQRfeFXqKrTJNF0y7HOYJXEFqtGJpMhjRiRLy7QRDc_M9_PD7TZLFtZppqSvRPjsHNXgWzAL1kIItiqeBGIz5uzq9qO1AwQmNferF66WXAqsnXE9y0BkxrvidWAvhuG3dVx3hRf99sZjAMROXERpLjrLpaYe3gN88xSNxdrgjwAwY5M28=&lang=gp) .

Comment: Apparently, you are looking for many primality tests. A motivation to prove or disprove them woule be to show that they would be efficient in practice.

Answer (score 1):

It holds true. The proof is much the same, with minor changes due to
$$ P_n^{(a)}(x) = \frac{n}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n-k}{k} \frac{a^k(2x)^{n-2k}}{n-k}.$$
For odd prime $n$, we see that the coefficient of $x^n$ is $2^{n-1}$, and others are divisible by $n$. For odd composite $n$, we take a prime $p$ dividing $n$ and show that $n$ doesn't divide the coefficient of $x^p$.

Answer (score 0):

I fear this is not true.$$P_n^{(5)}(x)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot\left(\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+5}\right)^9+\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+5}\right)^9\right)$$One has
$$P_n^{(5)}(4)=126336484=9(14037387)+1\\4^9=262144=9(29127)+1$$Therefore
$$P_n^{(5)}(4)\equiv 4^9\pmod9\space\space\text{but $9$ is not prime. }$$

Comment: Put this code into WolframAlpha : a=5;n=9;SameQ[PolynomialMod[(1/2)*((x-Sqrt[x^2+a])^n+(x+Sqrt[x^2+a])^n),n],x^n]

Comment: The question is about a polynomial identity, and not about specific values of 'x'.